# Using ImageResizer and getting Red pixel on images indicating a licence issue

Tags: image, model-view-controller, imageresizer

I'm getting red pixels added to my uploaded images - using ImageResizer 4.2.5. After reading a bunch of posts about this same issue, I am none the wiser with actually understanding how their licencing works - nor why the version I'm using is violating any licencing - I'm after the bare bones free version (which is what I thought I was using).

Any help would be appreciated. A slightly confused newbie.

Below is their output ...

```
Diagnostics for ImageResizer 4.2.5 9bd2b12e at www.gotheextramile.com.au generated 9/12/2019 4:24:49 AM UTC
Please remember to provide this page when contacting support.

---------------------- Licensing ON ----------------------
License status for active features (for Process):
No licenses found

Need to change domains? Get a discounted upgrade to a floating license: https://imageresizing.net/licenses/convert

You are using <licenses licenseError='Watermark'>. If there is a licensing error, an red dot will be drawn on the bottom-right corner of each image. This can be set to 'Exception' instead (valuable if you are storing results).
---------------------- Licensing ON ----------------------

You are using ImageResizer Performance Edition plugins.

1 issues detected:

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.






Configuration:

<resizer>
<plugins>
<add name="DiskCache" />
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.LicenseDisplay
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.LicenseVerifier.LicenseEnforcer`1[ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.DiskCache]
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs.PrettyGifs

Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, colors, dither, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/10.0 on Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will limit ram usage !!
Executing assembly: D:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Installed HttpModules: 

System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key UrlRoutingModule-4.0)
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key ScriptModule-4.0)
System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key OutputCache)
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key Session)
System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key WindowsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key FormsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key DefaultAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key RoleManager)
System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key UrlAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key FileAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key AnonymousIdentification)
System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key Profile)
System.Web.UrlMappingsModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key UrlMappingsModule)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key ServiceModel-4.0)
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key ApplicationInsightsWebTracking)
ImageResizer.InterceptModule, ImageResizer, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null          (under key ImageResizingModule)
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key __DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_34e40b87-a8f2-4632-a238-7cc4cc2f844e)
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key __DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_a3eb5620-ee01-4024-bf63-913f0509329e)
System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key __DynamicModule_System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_2e339333-bf04-4ed5-8a09-7301aec6b2e5)

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 File: 4.7.3460.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3460.0                     
System.Web                               File: 4.7.3429.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3429.0                     
System                                   File: 4.7.3451.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3451.0                     
System.Core                              File: 4.7.3429.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3429.0                     
System.Configuration                     File: 4.7.3324.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3324.0                     
System.Xml                               File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Web.ApplicationServices           File: 4.7.3429.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3429.0                     
System.Runtime.Caching                   File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Web.RegularExpressions            File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots      File: 1.1.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
Microsoft.JScript                        File: 14.7.3062.0 (10.0.0.0)    Informational: 14.7.3062.0                    
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform File: 1.0.40810.0 (1.0.7.0)     Informational: 1.0.7-40810                    
EnvSettings                              File: 86.0.7.46 (1.0.0.0)       Informational: 86.0.7.46 (master-108102a905d)  
Microsoft.CSharp                         File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Data                              File: 4.7.3260.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3260.0                     
System.Web.Services                      File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Drawing                           File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.EnterpriseServices                File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.IdentityModel                     File: 4.7.3440.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3440.0                     
System.Runtime.Serialization             File: 4.7.3440.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3440.0                     
System.ServiceModel                      File: 4.7.3440.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3440.0                     
System.ServiceModel.Activation           File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.ServiceModel.Web                  File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Activities                        File: 4.7.3440.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3440.0                     
System.ServiceModel.Activities           File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.WorkflowServices                  File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Web.Extensions                    File: 4.7.3429.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3429.0                     
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Xml.Linq                          File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Web.DynamicData                   File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
Antlr3.Runtime                           File: 3.4.1.9004 (3.4.1.9004)   Informational:                                
EntityFramework                          File: 6.2.61023.0 (6.0.0.0)     Informational: 6.2.0-61023                    
EntityFramework.SqlServer                File: 6.2.61023.0 (6.0.0.0)     Informational: 6.2.0-61023                    
EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact         File: 6.2.61023.0 (6.0.0.0)     Informational: 6.2.0-61023                    
ImageResizer                             File: 4.2.5.1116 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.2.5 9bd2b12e                 
ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache           File: 4.2.5.1116 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.2.5 9bd2b12e                 Performance Edition
ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs          File: 4.2.5.1116 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.2.5 9bd2b12e                 Performance Edition
log4net                                  File: 2.0.8.0 (2.0.8.0)         Informational: 2.0.8.0-.NET 4.5               
Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept             File: 2.0.6.39073 (2.0.6.0)     Informational:                                
Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector         File: 2.2.0.738 (2.2.0.0)       Informational:                                
Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector        File: 2.2.0.738 (2.2.0.0)       Informational:                                
Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel      File: 2.2.0.54039 (2.2.0.0)     Informational:                                
Microsoft.AI.Web                         File: 2.2.0.738 (2.2.0.0)       Informational:                                
Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer               File: 2.2.0.738 (2.2.0.0)       Informational:                                
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights            File: 2.2.0.54037 (2.2.0.0)     Informational:                                
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core           File: 2.2.2.70424.0 (2.0.0.0)   Informational:                                
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework File: 2.2.2.70424.0 (2.0.0.0)   Informational:                                
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin           File: 2.2.2.70424.0 (2.0.0.0)   Informational:                                
Microsoft.Owin                           File: 4.0.70213.103 (4.0.0.0)   Informational: 4.0.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb            File: 4.0.70213.103 (4.0.0.0)   Informational: 4.0.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies          File: 3.0.40213.64 (3.0.1.0)    Informational: 3.0.1                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security                  File: 4.0.70213.103 (4.0.0.0)   Informational: 4.0.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook         File: 4.0.70213.103 (4.0.0.0)   Informational: 4.0.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google           File: 4.0.70213.103 (4.0.0.0)   Informational: 4.0.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount File: 4.0.70213.103 (4.0.0.0)   Informational: 4.0.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth            File: 4.0.70213.103 (4.0.0.0)   Informational: 4.0.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter          File: 4.0.70213.103 (4.0.0.0)   Informational: 4.0.0                          
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks                File: 1.0.168.0 (1.0.12.0)      Informational: 1.0.168.0                      
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop File: 1.0.168.0 (1.0.168.0)     Informational: 1.0.168.0                      
Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions     File: 1.0.168.0 (1.0.12.0)      Informational: 1.0.168.0                      
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             File: 1.0.20105.407 (1.0.0.0)   Informational:                                
Newtonsoft.Json                          File: 11.0.2.21924 (11.0.0.0)   Informational: 11.0.2                         
Owin                                     File: 1.0 (1.0.0.0)             Informational:                                
PagedList                                File: 1.17 (1.17.0.0)           Informational:                                
PagedList.Mvc                            File: 4.5 (4.5.0.0)             Informational:                                
PayPal                                   File: 1.9.1 (1.9.1.0)           Informational:                                
SendGrid                                 File: 9.8.0.0 (9.8.0.0)         Informational: 9.9.0                          
SendGrid.SmtpApi                         File: 1.1.3.0 (1.1.3.0)         Informational:                                
SendGridMail                             File: 5.1.0 (5.1.0.0)           Informational:                                
System.Data.SqlServerCe                  File: 4.0.8876.1 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.0                            
System.Net.Http.Formatting               File: 5.2.60510.0 (5.2.6.0)     Informational: 5.2.6-60510 (3155d174ba1d7e281ef0b9bbe78fb10a43aa7450)  
System.Web.Helpers                       File: 3.0.30128.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  
System.Web.Mvc                           File: 5.2.30128.0 (5.2.3.0)     Informational: 5.2.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  
System.Web.Optimization                  File: 1.1.40211.0 (1.1.0.0)     Informational:                                
System.Web.Razor                         File: 3.0.30128.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           File: 3.0.30128.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  
System.Web.WebPages                      File: 3.0.30128.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                File: 3.0.30128.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.3-30128 (0e974218e12a67d4b1f25422119e40cfe6953e46)  
Walk                                     File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
WebGrease                                File:  (1.5.2.14234)            Informational:                                
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           File: 1.0.20105.407 (1.0.0.0)   Informational:                                
Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Tracing            File: 86.0.7.46 (1.0.0.0)       Informational: 86.0.7.46 (master-108102a905d)  
System.Data.Services.Design              File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Runtime                           File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
App_global.asax.ypwz-rsv                 File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
System.ServiceModel.Internals            File: 4.7.3440.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3440.0                     
SMDiagnostics                            File: 4.7.3440.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3440.0                     
System.Xaml.Hosting                      File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Data.Linq                         File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Net.Http                          File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Threading.Tasks                   File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Transactions                      File: 4.7.3221.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3221.0                     
System.Web.DataVisualization             File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Numerics                          File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Xaml                              File: 4.7.3429.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3429.0                     
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
System.Data.OracleClient                 File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework File:  (1.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework File:  (1.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
System.Net.Http.WebRequest               File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
System.Web.Mobile                        File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-Walk       File:  (1.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.4os6h2nz   File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_svjup3ob                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
System.Dynamic                           File: 4.7.3062.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.3062.0                     
App_Web_m3tpf0so                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_fsvlstrt                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics File: 86.0.7.46 (1.0.0.0)       Informational: 86.0.7.46 (master-108102a905d)  
Microsoft.Azure.Websites.StorageSdk      File: 4.3.0.0 (4.3.0.0)         Informational:                                
App_Web_qwv0ti0q                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_3gq3bhqt                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_a31kmxzd                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_4o2d3v0a                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_totbzguv                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_index.cshtml.7934d0d.b6bpjstw    File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_1gibf4y5                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_rreh35sb                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_mdewlqhr                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_xvs1dxd3                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
The most recent license fetch used the following URL:




When fetching a remote license file (if you have one), the following information is sent via the querystring.
                         license_id [integer]
                         manager_id [guid]
                   total_heartbeats [integer]
                     new_heartbeats [integer]
                    first_heartbeat [integer]
                  reporting_version 4
                            proc_64 0
                          proc_guid hD35XBnxT02ZpjS0G7YiQw
                    proc_sys_dotnet 4.7 or later
                           proc_iis 10.0
           proc_integrated_pipeline 1
                       proc_id_hash vlIgxBAt
                   proc_asyncmodule 0
              proc_default_commands 
                proc_working_set_mb 41
                    proc_git_commit 9bd2b12e
                  proc_info_version 4.2.5
                  proc_file_version 4.2.5.1116
                  proc_apppath_hash t3FzIQCp
                                mod .Routing.UrlRoutingModule
                                mod .Handlers.ScriptModule
                                mod .Caching.OutputCacheModule
                                mod .SessionState.SessionStateModule
                                mod .WindowsAuthenticationModule
                                mod .FormsAuthenticationModule
                                mod .DefaultAuthenticationModule
                                mod .RoleManagerModule
                                mod .UrlAuthorizationModule
                                mod .FileAuthorizationModule
                                mod .AnonymousIdentificationModule
                                mod .Profile.ProfileModule
                                mod .UrlMappingsModule
                                mod System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule
                                mod Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule
                                mod ImageResizer.InterceptModule
                                mod Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule
                                mod .WebPages.WebPageHttpModule
                                mod .Optimization.BundleModule
                    h_logical_cores 1
                       h_mac_digest 1Do7kOs3IEDsU4q2VD6c8Q
                             h_os64 1
             h_network_drives_count 0
               h_other_drives_count 1
               h_fixed_drives_count 2
                      h_fixed_drive NTFS,20,37
                      h_fixed_drive NTFS*,2,33
                                  p SizeLimiting
                                  p DiskCache
                                  p PrettyGifs
                diskcache_autoclean 0
              diskcache_asyncwrites 0
               diskcache_subfolders 8192
            diskcache_network_drive 0
               diskcache_filesystem NTFS
              diskcache_drive_avail 2408361984
              diskcache_drive_total 33990635520
              diskcache_virtualpath /imagecache
                        postauth_ok 83470
                source_multiple_8x8 4
                 source_multiple_x8 4
              counter_update_failed 0
                source_multiple_4x4 4
              source_multiple_16x16 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DiskCache and PrettyGifs plugins are Performance Edition.