# Red dot appears on ImageResizer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer

I am using imageresizer, however there's a red dot on the image, although i am not using any paid plugin, below are the plugin i am using:

1. ImageResizer.dll
2. DiskCache.dll
3. PrettyGifs.dll

below is my querystring with the image:

```
image.jpg?w=100&h=50&mode=crop
```

Although i tried without crop as well and the results are still same. I checked debug.ashx and it says i am using Performance Edition plugins, however i don't have any plugins except above. It also mentions

```
You are using <licenses licenseError='Watermark'>. If there is a licensing error, an red dot will be drawn on the bottom-right corner of each image. This can be set to 'Exception' instead (valuable if you are storing results).
```

Can anyone suggest, why the red dot is appearing.

Comment: It certainly sounds like you have what the error message calls "a licensing error".  Look here: [ImageResizer: Installing a License Key](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/install/license_keys) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242905/).  NOTE: Just because you've installed "Performance Edition" (which DiskCache and PrettyGifs are part of) ... doesn't mean you've correctly configured your license. The ImageResizer link above has several good troubleshooting tips.

Comment: ok currently my requirement is to just crop image with the width and height i provide, can i achieve this with the Free Version of imageresizer? does crop has anything to do with DiskCache and PrettyGifs and how i do remove it, is it just that i need to remove the resizer section having DiskCache and PrettyGifs plugin in web.config?

Answer (score 0):

DiskCache and PrettyGifs are both paid plugins (unless you're AGPL-compliant).

Disk caching is quite important for production sites, since they can be easily overwhelmed if results aren't cached. Image processing takes significant CPU time and RAM.

If you're doing a new project, you should use Imageflow instead of ImageResizer, as it's the newer, better replacement: https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server